# Connecting to WCF service from SharePoint

Tags: event-receivers, wcf

I have a WCF service that lives on another server that I am trying to connect to from an EventReciever in a SharePoint 2010 feature.  I have gone through all the hoops of configuring the feature in the web application's web.config file, installed the certificates, and I have verified I can see the web service from IE on that machine.  When I try to trigger the service in SharePoint, I get this error:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do at this point.  A lot of other sources on the web say this is a timing issue on the server, but wouldn't that nerf Internet Explorer, too?

Thanks,

- Matt

*Edit 4:11PM 5/24/2012*
OK, I made a few edits to the solution in visual studio (which I am leery of because someone else wrote it) and was able to get an inner exception:

> [System.ServiceModel.FaultException] = {"At least one security token
>   in the message could not be validated."}

*Edit 11:23AM 5/25/2012*

I created a test application on the same machine as the sharepoint server and ran some tests with that.  So at least it's not a sharepoint issue, specifically, since that little winforms app is having the same problem.

In the FaultException there's a property called "Code" which is a "FaultCode" object.  Two properties of this strike me as possibly useful:  isSenderFault = true and Name = "Sender"

Not sure if that will help anybody give good tips but at least it's more.

*Edit 11:50AM 6/1/2012*

Still no luck connecting to the wcf service. The winforms app does not work when placed directly on the server hosting the service, either, with the same error.

Comment: Any chances you can get the details from the inner fault exception?

Comment: OK, inner exception found.  I'll do some googling on this in the mean time.

Comment: What kind of WCF binding are you using and how is the authentication provider in SharePoint configured (classic mode, claims mode, kerberos, etc...)? Can you post the service configuration from both web.configs (client and service)? Have you enabled WIF logging on the web service?

Comment: I can do this on Monday, but SharePoint is in Claims mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

group, and thank you for your contributions to this question.  I really appreciate it.  I found out what the problem is, though - at the Service end of the chain I had a connection string pointing at a different user database, so the user trying to connect was not getting recognized.  Hopefully THAT helps someone, because it was a real egg-on-face moment for me and I would never have figured it out until I re-installed the whole operation from the ground up.  Fortunately I had a colleague who took some time and he actually did look at everything from the ground up and thusly discovered the erroneous connection string.

- Matt

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are using the [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331) which simplifies accesses between services. There is a four-part series on accessing WCF services using SharePoint that may provide you with more information. The following two posts may be directly relevant to your development effort -

- [WCF: Determining Caller Identity within WCF Web Services (Part 2 of 4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg318617)
- [WCF: Establishing Trust Between WCF Web Services and SharePoint 2010 Security Token Service (Part 3 of 4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg318614)

Also, if you are using Event Receivers to access the external services - keep in mind the type of event handlers as they behave differently: [synchronous or asynchronous](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/).

**UPDATE:** One approach would be to verify the communications between SharePoint (or your test Winform app) & WCF services using network tools like Microsoft NetMon, WireShark, Sniffer, etc. If you are using Internet Explorer 9 (IE9) - there is a provision to look at [the Network Traffic too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not trying to develop anything here, this service and feature should already work.  I'm just trying to deploy the thing to staging.  Never touched it before this week.  So either there is some .config issue on my part or the security certs are messed up.  I have no clue if this thing talks to STS or not, but it really doesn't look like it does.

Comment: I have posted an update to my above response by suggesting a network monitoring approach. Hope it helps.

Comment: if I go to the service URL it has no problem - IE just says it takes 250 ms to get the page.  It doesn't say anything in the Network Traffic tool about the security aspect.

Comment: the tools were to verify if bidirectional communications were established.

Comment: I'm going to upvote your answer because I think you put out some good information, although this did not solve my problem.